# How can I close the screen after import task from oracle for toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

I imported some data to database using toad for oracle.
And I expected closing the import screen automatically but it didn't work.
How can I close the import screen automatically when import end?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have to close it manually.